# Run-time error 1004 with Range.Autofilter in Excel VBA 2016

Tags: vba, excel

My code is

```
With ActiveSheet
   .AutoFilterMode = False
   .Range("23:23").AutoFilter
End With
```

**This works fine in Excel 2010**, but with Excel 2016 I get:-

> Run-time error '1004'
>   AutoFilter method of Range class failed

**Also, I can manually click the filter icon in the Ribbon (Under Data > Filter) but cannot do this with VBA code**

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `AutoFilter` gives `1004` error, when you are trying to filter by an empty row. Try to put something on row `23` and to filter it again like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    With ActiveSheet
       .AutoFilterMode = False
       .Range("23:23").Cells(1) = 1
       .Range("23:23").Cells(2) = 2
       .Range("23:23").AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

If it works, then you simply do not have values in row 23, thus it cannot apply an autofilter.

---

In general, the `AutoFilter` in Excel has some strange behaviour. E.g., if you open a new Excel file and you run the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet
       .AutoFilterMode = False
       '.Range("23:23").Cells(1) = 1
       '.Range("23:23").Cells(2) = 2
       .Range("23:23").AutoFilter
    End With    
End Sub
```

It will give you the `1004` error. Let's call this time momentum **FirstTime**.

Then, if you uncomment the two ranges and run it, the `AutoFilter` would appear.

Now the *strange* part - delete all cells from the sheet, comment back the two ranges and it really looks like the way it was, at the **FirstTime**. But if you run the code it will put an AutoFilter on the empty 23rd row without a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely do have values, as this code works fine in Excel 2010

Comment: @RShome - on your place I would try it. The `AutoFilter` is a bit more difficult and has some strange behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried above but still getting the same error.

Comment: It works absolutely fine in Excel 2010 that's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Existing filer and Run it again